# Passing JMeter user variable across beanshell script in different threads

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

What I'm trying to do is pass variable between the threads in JMeter - so one thread modify this value and next one will get it - please look at this structure:

```
Test Plan
    User Defined Variables
    Thread Group 1
        BSF PreProcessor
    Thread Group 2
        HTTP Request
```

1. User Defined Variables:

   ```
   Name:  myvar
   Value: foo
   ```
2. Thread Group 1 -> BSF PreProcessor:

   Script: `vars.put("myvar","users");`
3. Thread Group 2 -> HTTP Request:

   Path: `/api/${myvar}`

What I've got from Thread Group 2 step - variable `myvar` with default value:

```
${myvar} == foo
```

but I want to persist value assigned to variable `myvar` in Thread Group 1 step so in Thread Group 2 I will get:

```
${myvar} == users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/InterThreadCommunication

Also check :

- [How do I pass a variable from one Thread Group to another in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter)

Comment: I'm currently added jmeter-plugins so following your answer I used  Thread Communication Processors and that solved my problem Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a different problem where user defined variables are messed up between thread groups: ThreadGroup_1 picks up user defined variables from ThreadGroup_2, and vice versa