# Jmeter running two threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I need two users on web page both have different actions and login so I am using two threads (Login--action--Logout)

now I want user2 to start after user1 has completed 100 requests and user1 is still continuing 101,102,.....

how do I do this?

I think I cannot use delays as sometime 100 requests may take 100 sec or 90 sec etc.

is there any way to start another thread in between the running of present thread

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two different users with two sets of actions that should be done at two different times, it sounds to me like you want to use two different Thread Groups. Make sure to use `Run Thread Group Consecutively`.

[image: Sequential Thread Groups]

Comment: thanks But my problem is different My scenario is like this: one user keeps on creating records for 2 days, other user view one record after every 100 records are created

Comment: Ah. You're probably going to want to do something with properties- use some sort of wait loop in the second thread that waits until the first thread sets that property. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter.