# build jmeter-parellarel-request-master

Tags: api, github, jmeter

I need to write a scenario where we make several calls to an API in parallel with JMeter. The solution is based on OAuth, where a token is extracted and passed along with every call made to the API. This works fine, however, JMeter has no built-in option to make multiple parallel calls. I could divide them into separate thread groups, but this would not be desired.

- Thread group

  - oauth calls to get token
  - extract token
  - api call /getCustomerActions
  - api call /getCustomerBlabla1..
  - api call /getCustomerBlabla2..

I've found the following custom sampler by Franz See:

https://github.com/franz-see/jmeter-parellarel-request

As I'm not big on development/compiling, my question would be how do I compile this package and use in in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).
2. Download [latest jmeter-parallel-request release](https://github.com/franz-see/jmeter-parellarel-request/releases)
3. Unpack downloaded sources and switch to that folder
4. Invoke `maven package` command from that folder
5. Copy file from `target/jmeter-parallel-request-xx.jar` to JMeter's `lib/ext` folder
6. Restart JMeter to pick the plugin up

You can also check out [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin seems to work, but using it as a seperate thread group, all extracted values or tokens from other (main) threads are not captured.. too bad

Comment: Any other solution to tackle this?

Comment: use propertties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter