# Running sequential threadgroup depending the result of earlier threadgroup - JMeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

After reading this [Running multiple Thread Groups sequentially in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321662/running-multiple-thread-groups-sequentially-in-jmeter) It seems to me that it is possible. But I am not finding a way.

I have a scenario like:

1. I have user login and pass and login page url - So have to login with that
2. After Successful login, submit a form data having approximately 15+ fields and upload a file in form as well
3. After successful submission, load another page and then send logout request.

And I have a set of users in an excel or a csv file. 100 or 500 user, need to check this same process for all those seperate user at a time and sequentailly(1 after another)

**Is it possible to do with JMeter?** I can create threadgroup to submit a form data with httpwebrequest. but don't know any way to do the above type of task.

***I will not use blaze meter.

Here is another link which also indicate its possible:

[Dependency among multiple thread groups in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265806/dependency-among-multiple-thread-groups-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below config:-
In thread group, put thread as 1 and loop count forever
[image]

Below is the CSV data set config.
[image]

Put all your requests (for end to end scenerio) under one thread group.

With this, one thread will run sequentially based on the inputs from csv. So, if it is 100 users in csv, thread will loop 100 times for all the requests.

Above plan is considering one thread group, but if you have multiple thread groups then use the option in the "Test Plan" to run thread group in a sequence.
But, if it is one end to end flow you dont need to have different thread group.
Hope this helps.