# JMeter extract link using regular expression pass into next request with blank values

Tags: regex, foreach, controller, jmeter, beanshell

This is how I have Test Plan set up:

HTTP Request -> Regular Expression Extractor to extract multiple links  - This is extracting correctly -- But some of the links are Blank
[RegularExpressionExtractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d8bn.png) ---  `<a href="(.*)" class="product-link">`

BeanShell Sampler - to filter blank or null values -- This works fine

[BeanShell Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1hEg.png)

```
log.info("Enter Beanshell Sampler");
matches = vars.get("url_matchNr");
log.info(matches);

for (Integer i=1; i < Integer.parseInt(matches); i++) 
{
    String url = vars.get("url_"+i);
    //log.info(url1);
    if(url != null @and url.length() > 0)
    {
        log.info(i+"->" + url);
        //return url;
        //vars.put("url2", url);
        vars.put("url2", url);
        //props.put("url2", url);
        log.info("URL2:" + vars.get("url2"));
    }
}
```

ForEach Controller
[ForEach Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yc4T.png)

[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knomw.png)

The problem I am facing is ForEach Controller runs through all the values including `Blank` or `NULL` -- How can I run the loop only for the non null blank values

Answer (score 1):

You should change your regular expression to exclude empty value

Instead of using any value including empty using `*` sign

```
 <a href="(.*)" class="product-link">
```

Find only not empty strings using `+` sign:

```
 <a href="(.+)" class="product-link">
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan as well.  <a href="(.+)" class="product-link"> worked fine now NULL are being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier, you should change your regex!

you can replace it directly by

```
<a href="(.+)" class="product-link">
```

or by something more constraining like this:

```
<a href="^((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)$" class="product-link">
```

which is a regex to match only URLs.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149

> The first capturing group is all option. It allows the URL to begin
>   with "http://", "https://", or neither of them. I have a question mark
>   after the s to allow URL's that have http or https. In order to make
>   this entire group optional, I just added a question mark to the end of
>   it.
>
> Next is the domain name: one or more numbers, letters, dots, or hypens
>   followed by another dot then two to six letters or dots. The following
>   section is the optional files and directories. Inside the group, we
>   want to match any number of forward slashes, letters, numbers,
>   underscores, spaces, dots, or hyphens. Then we say that this group can
>   be matched as many times as we want. Pretty much this allows multiple
>   directories to be matched along with a file at the end. I have used
>   the star instead of the question mark because the star says zero or
>   more, not zero or one. If a question mark was to be used there, only
>   one file/directory would be able to be matched.
>
> Then a trailing slash is matched, but it can be optional. Finally we
>   end with the end of the line.
>
> String that matches:
>
> http://net.tutsplus.com/about
>
> String that doesn't match:
>
> http://google.com/some/file!.html (contains an exclamation point)

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

ForEach controller doesn't work with JMeter Properties, you need to change the "Input Variable Prefix" to `url_2` and your test should start working as expected.

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy language for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy language on next available opportunity.

[Groovy has much better performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) while Beanshell might become a bottleneck when it comes to immense loads.

Comment: In Beanshell Sampler I have this
 for (Integer i=1; i < Integer.parseInt(matches); i++) 
{
 String url = vars.get("url_"+i);
 //log.info(url1);

 if(url != null @and url.length() > 0)
 
 {
 log.info(i+"->" + url);
 //l1=__javaScript(url.length);
 //log.info("Length:"+l1);
 //return url;
vars.put("url2", url);

//props.put("url2", url);
log.info("URL2:" + vars.get("url2"));

 }
    
}  In ForEachController  Input Variable I am using ${url2} and Output Variable url_out but its not working

Comment: Of course it will not be working, I would suggest re-read my answer as many times as it will be required to see what you should put at the "Input Variable Prefix"

Comment: Using url_2 works great. Now I want to extend this further and use the url into another thread group and use more than 1 threads. I used this option https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups and it passes the value to the HTTP sampler successfully but I need to use the property value into the for each controller which I understand not possible then I tried this option  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter some how this didn't work either do you have any simpler way?