# jmeter pass variable between threads

Tags: multithreading, foreach, controller, jmeter

> TestPlan Thread Group HTTP Request1 ->Regular Expression Extractor - Return 10 Results - URLs -- **Single Thread**
>   ForEach Controller - Using variable from extractor - Successfully Loops through above results HTTP Request2 ->Regular Expression Extractor - Return 10 Results
>   This above is under 1 thread

I want to have ForEach Controller under different thread --run multiple therads and use the URLs extracted from 1 thread HTTP Sampler  -- I tried to use these two approaches
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups
[How do I pass a variable from one Thread Group to another in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter)
 but somehow now managed it to work
Please help

Answer (score 0):

[ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) will not work with JMeter Properties, it is designed to work only with JMeter Variables so if you want to pass them between different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will need to do some scripting.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the Regular Expression Extractor and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   vars.entrySet().each { var ->
       if (var.getKey().startsWith('foo')) {
           props.put(var.getKey(), var.getValue())
       }
   }
   ```

   replace `foo` with what you have as a `Reference Name` in the Regular Expression Extractor. The above code will convert all variables which names start with `foo` into the relevant JMeter Properties
2. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to the second Thread Group (you don't need to measure time of properties to variables conversion, do you)
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Test Action sampler
4. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   props.entrySet().each {prop ->
       if (prop.getKey().startsWith('foo')){
           vars.put(prop.getKey(),prop.getValue())
       }
   }
   ```

   the above code convert JMeter Properties into JMeter Variables so you will be able to use them in the ForEach Controller in the second Thread Group. Again, replace this `foo` with the reference name of your own variable.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: i have reference name:inputKitchenLevel1

Comment: i have reference name:inputKitchenLevel1. In JSR223 PostProcessor i have this code vars.entrySet().each { var ->
    if (var.getKey().startsWith('input')) {
        props.put(var.getKey(), var.getValue())
    }
}  language is selected as groovy - 2nd thread Test Action -> JSR223 PreProcessor with code  props.entrySet().each {prop ->
    if (prop.getKey().startsWith('input')){
        vars.put(prop.getKey(),prop.getValue())
    }
} foreach controller - input variable prefix : ${inputKitchenLevel1}  but I am getting an error

Comment: error at the   JSR223 PostProcessor     ERROR javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
 at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:42) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:833) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]