# JMeter - execute JSR223 Sampler or PreProcessor JSR223 before user defined parameters

Tags: jmeter

I try to load values from properties file using simple JSR 223 Sampler using BeanShell which I do successfully simple like this :

```
for (String key : localConfigProp.stringPropertyNames()) {
                String value = localConfigProp.getProperty(key);
                props.put(key,value); 
}
```

now i have UDV controller which i try to load from property to variable

```
test_param  ${__property(test_param,,${test_param_default} )}
```

the UDV controller in after the JSR223 Sampler the problem is that in windows 
the test_param  do set its value from the property file and in linux
the test_param still holds its default ${test_param_default} value
i guess it got something to do with this that the UDV controller is invoked first.

how can I make the script invoked before the UDV?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** make the script invoked before the [UDV](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables).

> The User Defined Variables element lets you define an initial set of variables, just as in the Test Plan.
>
> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

You can either replace UDV with [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) Pre Processor

> For defining variables during a test run, see User Parameters

Or update variable in [JSR223 Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using `vars`:

> vars - (JMeterVariables) - gives read/write access to variables:

```
vars.put("variableName", "newValue");
```

Variable will be updated in next steps when it will be used (not in UDV) as `${variableName}`

**EDIT**

If you want to copy property to variable - you can add in value `${__P(START.HMS)}`.

For JSR223 element you can use

```
vars.put("variableName", props.get("START.HMS"));
```

Comment: User Parameters accepts variables ? i can use the __P helper ?

Comment: @user63898 you want to copy property to variable? you can add in value `${__P(START.HMS)}`. for JSR223 you can use `vars.put("a", props.get("START.HMS"));`

Comment: i want define the test plan variables in UDV or any other GUI controller 
I dont what to set the user variables in script . i tried User properties controller but it force me to do it in each Thread group 
can't i set it once in setUP group ?

Comment: No, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707832/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-thread-group-to-another-in-jmeter but you can Add `Test Fragement` and reuse it in multiple thread groups.

Comment: amazing such simple task but so complex to implement

Comment: UDV is a pain in the... JMeter

Comment: In general for dynamic/multi thread group parameters you should work with JMeter properties